# Magento 1.3.2.2: Fatal error: Call to a member function getUsername() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento, admin, fatal-error

In Magento 1.3.2.2 we get a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getUsername() on a non-object in 
.../app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/header.phtml on line 31
```

During an order confirmation, Magento should make a transition to the success page. But we are getting that error instead.

An Admin header is shown with this error. If I refresh, I get to the success page where I should have been taken if everything was ok.

Comment: Hi! Did you've managed to solve this? I'm getting this issue in the 1.7.0.0 version also?

Comment: Have the problem with 1.7 too.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens because header.phtml on line 31 has entry:

```
$this->getUser()->getUsername();
```

But getUser() method didn't return valid object. This method pretty simple and looks like this:

```
return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
```

So, you should debug only one place: app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
Only one method setUser() object to session

```
public function login($username, $password, $request = null) {
    ...
    $this->setUser($user);
```

If user object loads and valid it is mean that you have problem with session it self:

- check how cookies sets
- cookies path and created time

It is not easy find the problem remotely without debugging. So I wish you success.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and solved it as follows:

1. Backup the var folder as (var-back)
2. Create a new var directory
3. Backup the locks folder as (locks-back) {if available}
4. Create the locks directory

Refresh the URL